# Prevent redirect loop in website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-redirect

i'm a user of a site (of which I have no control on) which sometimes presents a redirect loop (page A redirects to B, and B to A). Removing a specific cookie fixes the issue. I'd like to automatize the suppression of that cookie when a direct loop is detected.
I was thinking of developing a small chrome extension for that effect (which would be the first plugin I write). Would that work?
I tried using the webRequest API (onBeforeRedirect), but it doesn't seem to catch the redirect.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "name",
  "description": "description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>","webRequest","webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["test.js"],
    "persistent": true
  }
}
```

And here is my test.js:

```
var callback = function(details) {
    console.log("redirect caught!");
};

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(callback);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You mean like this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg

Comment: @sksallaj no, not really, unless this extension is capable of detecting a redirect loop and removing a cookie when it detects it?

Comment: Just a bit curious.. Why do you need the cookie when you first load it.. Why not just prevent the cookie and be done with it? Also.. Instead of blocking, you could change the value of what's inside the cookie.

Comment: The cookie is used for authentication, so I can't change its value nor delete it (or I would have to reauthenticate). I just want to delete it when a loop is detected. Is that possible? What's wrong with my code?